# Is there any way to scroll beyond the last line in xcode?

Tags: xcode

I ask if there is any way to scroll beyond the last line in xcode, because I always end up pressing a lot of enters to the end of my files, so that I don't have to always type my code at the bottom of my window.

I have skimmed through the properties panel of XCode, and had a look at [this forum](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/253478-scrolling-in-xcode-editor.html). So far the answer looks negative, but I kept my hopes up. :)

Any ideas for tricking XCode to scroll beyond the last line? (I have XCode 4.5.2)

Comment: I don't think this is possible because the number of people demanding this feature is presumable very low.

Comment: Well, in vim they had this already! Now, I have checked Qt and on mac it does not have it either since it uses a simple scrollable textarea. Arghhh :(

Comment: checked emacs and pico too, not there by default... curious :S but sublime editor has it too!

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this? Typing at the bottom of the window just feels so unnatural!

Comment: My workaround was to press lots of enters at the end of the file. :S

Comment: I really wish this feature existed in Xcode. I use IntelliJ for web applications and it has this feature. It's so difficult staring at the bottom of the screen in Xcode.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs Could you please accept my answer if it satisfies you ? :) Thanks !

Comment: @nverinaud sorry, I missed your answer. The plugin looks quite cool! +1 Let me try it when I get home and if it works for me, you'll get the tick too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCode has it built-in:

Preferences -> Text Editing -> Editor Overscroll.

Comment: which XCode version supports it?

Comment: @BarneySzabolcs Starting with Xcode 10 should support it

Comment: @BarneySzabolcs I was so happy that I could give up adding spaces at the end :)

Answer (score 17):

There is now a plugin for that !

Have a look at [SCXcodeEditorInset](https://libraries.io/alcatraz/SCXcodeEditorInset) !

Comment: Apparently plugins are no longer supported starting with Xcode 8.

Comment: Yeah, only some limited kinds of plugins are supported, but no longer this one. 

Answer (score 3):

Dont think there is a way to do this but if you are trying to edit the buttom of the code while having it near the top of your display, you can click the middle view button in xcode to bring up the console/watcher and then drag that up to the desirable spot. This does decrease the overall space of your editor but can sometimes be useful if you prefer this or just need to do that temporarily

Comment: It is really a shame that the answer you provided is the best we are going to get :<

Comment: There is a solution now. See my response :)

Answer (score 0):

What I do is, When you finished typing at the bottom, before you go to top, type some unnecessary code "asdf" as error then go where you want. you can come back clicking on top right red error panel.

Comment: It is really a shame that the answer you provided is the best we are going to get :<